# Why return value from a function following local declaration in bash is always 0?

Tags: bash

In a script of bash below, I declare a variable followed by a function. And I tried to get the return value of the function. It should be 1 but it was always 0. When I remove the local declaration, it works as I want.
 Why local declaration breaks the return value of the following function?
 Is local declaration a type of command, like "if []"?
 Please let me know the reason.

My test function is following,

```
function inner_func() {
  local RETURN_00=1
  echo "RETURN_00 = $RETURN_00"
  echo "RETURN_00 = $RETURN_00" >&2
  return $RETURN_00
}

function func() {
  local ECHO_00=$(inner_func)  # this local declaration is a problem
  local RETURN_01=$?
  echo "RETURN_01 = $RETURN_01"
  echo "RETURN_01 = $RETURN_01" >&2
  return $RETURN_01
}

ECHO_01=$(func)
RESULT=$?
echo "RESULT = $RESULT"
```

Results of above code are following

```
RETURN_00 = 1
RETURN_01 = 0
RESULT = 0
```

Comment: BTW, this is something http://shellcheck.net/ catches and advises a fix to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`local` is a command of its own accord, so using it resets `$?` to `0` (assuming the local assignment is successful), so when you do:

```
local ECHO_00=$(inner_func)
local RETURN_01=$? # $? has already been reset to 0 by the command local on the previous line.
```

Instead you can do this:

```
local ECHO_00
ECHO_00=$(inner_func)
local RETURN_01=$?
```

That way `ECHO_00` is still local, but you can also access the return value from the function you called in the subshell. Output:

```
RETURN_00 = 1
RETURN_01 = 1
RESULT = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When a local variable is declared and assigned in the same command, the variable assignment takes place before the local declaration. So the value of $? is the return value of the local declaration operation.

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html (3rd grey block from the top)

Comment: Boo, hiss re: using the ABS as a reference. (Half of what the freenode #bash channel spends its time doing is helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up there; it's very much the w3schools of bash).

Comment: Fair enough, but I did verify that the example works without local declared and the explanation offered made sense to me. With and without local, the result is different.

Comment: Sure -- I'm not saying that the ABS is wrong in this particular case. Most of what makes it objectionable isn't outright incorrect information (and when it *is* outright incorrect, that's typically due to lack of maintenance), but examples that don't take care to avoid bad practices *unrelated to whatever they're showcasing at the time*, so folks who use its code samples as templates tend to end up with very buggy code.

Comment: ...which is to say, if you found an example *reinforcing the exact same point* using either the bash-hackers wiki or the wooledge wiki or the bash man page / info page as sources, those sources are less likely to lead people wrong.

Comment: ...in that particular page, we've got old-style test syntax usage without requisite quoting; we've got unquoted expansions elsewhere; we've got all-caps variable names (see fourth paragraph of POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html setting out conventions for naming of environment variables, with which shell variables share a namespace); we've got .sh extensions on scripts with bash (rather than POSIX sh) shebangs.

Comment: Thank you, mdewit, for telling me local declaration is an operation which generates another return value. And thank you, Charles Duffy, for telling me your experience. Both helped me a lot.